# maven zip uber-jar and shell script

Tags: shell, maven, jar, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-shade-plugin

I would like maven to combine an uber-jar created by the shade-plugin and a shell script from the all_files directory.

The project structure looks like this:

```
all_files/
    mvn_script.sh
    projB-shaded.jar

    maven_project/
        guide/
            parent-pom.xml
        projA/
            pom.xml
        projB/
            pom.xml
```

The jar is produced by projectB's pom file and then placed into the outtermost folder to be ready to be zipped with the shell script. The reason is so that the shell script can call the jar file to execute the project.

I want other programmers to be able to easily unzip the file and run the shell script without worry. And I also need to have maven package the script and jar together. I'm not sure exactly how to implement that within the shaded plugin.

Note: I do not want to use assembly-plugin because it doesn't package dependent jars well.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
          <outputFile>../../guide/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-shaded.jar</outputFile>
          <transformers>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
              <manifestEntries>
                <Main-Class>projB.classB</Main-Class>
              </manifestEntries>
            </transformer>
          </transformers>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use the `maven-assembly-plugin` for creating the uber-jar. But you will want to use it to create that ZIP.

Currently, your `maven-shade-plugin` is bound to the `package` phase. You could shift that execution to the `prepare-package` phase (since it actually prepares your final packaging) add an execution of the `maven-assembly-plugin` bound to the `package` phase. Your assembly would create a ZIP based on the shaded JAR (which will exist since the shade plugin will have been executed) and the shell script.

A sample descriptor would be the following:

```xml
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
    <id>your-id</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <files>
        <file>
            <source>${project.build.directory}/projB-shaded.jar</source>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        </file>
        <file>
            <source>/path/to/mvn_script.sh</source>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        </file>
    </files>
</assembly>
```

with the following POM configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <!-- current configuration -->
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>assemble</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>/path/to/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The typical location for the assembly descritor is under `src/assembly` as per the [Maven standard directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

Comment: How do I add both the files projB-shaded.jar and mvn_script.sh in to a single zip file?

Comment: Running shade in prepare-package causes it to fail.  It has to run in package it seems, or is there another configuration to allow it to run earlier?